# Understanding react js constructor in children component

Tags: reactjs, redux, constructor

I would like to understand the behavior of react component constructor. Let suppose I have three components - PageComponent, ListComponent, ItemComponent. My pseudo-code structure is:

PageComponent (get data from redux, fetch data)
ListComponent (obtains data as props, in loop (map) renders list of ItemComponents)
ItemComponent (obtains item data as props, renders item, manipulate data)

Logic:
 - when data in ItemComponent changes, changes are stored in REDUX and this change caused list re-rendering.

Use-case 1:
  - PageComponent renders ListComponent and ListComponent renders list of ItemComponets
  - when REDUX listItem data chages, PageComponent is updated, ListComponent is updated and ItemComponent CONSTRUCTOR is called (its local state is reset)

Use-case 2:
 - PageComponent renders only LIST (using map loop) of ItemComponents.
 - when REDUX listItem data chages, PageComponent is updated ItemComponent CONSTRUCTOR is NOT called (component is "only" updated) (and its local state is NOT reset)

Why there is a different behavior in these examples?

Source code:
PageComponent:

```js
import React from 'react'
...


class UsersPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        props.actions.getUsers();
    }

    render() {

        const {users} = this.props


        return (
            <Main>
                {/* // NO ITEM CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED
                    users.data.items.map((item, index) => {
                        return <ListItemComponent
                            data={item}
                            itemMethods={{
                                getItem: (data) => this.props.actions.getUser(data),
                                onEdit: (data) => this.props.actions.updateUser(data),
                                onDelete: (data) => this.props.actions.deleteUser(data),
                                validation: (data) => validateInput(this.props.strings, data)
                            }}
                            key={index}
                        />
                    })*/
                }
                { // ITEM CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED
                <ListComponent
                    loading={users.isFetching}
                    data={users.data}
                    methods={{
                        getItem: (data) => this.props.actions.getUser(data),
                        onEdit: (data) => this.props.actions.updateUser(data),
                        onDelete: (data) => this.props.actions.deleteUser(data),
                        validation: (data) => validateInput(this.props.strings, data)
                    }}
                />}
            </Main>
        );
    }
}

UsersPage.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    strings: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users,
        strings: state.strings.data || {},
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators({
            getUsers,
            getUser,
            addUser,
            updateUser,
            deleteUser,
        }, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withAlert(UsersPage));
```

ListComponent:

```js
import React from 'react'
...

class ListComponent extends React.Component {

    getList() {
        return <div className="list-outer">
           <Row>
             {
              items.map((item, index) => {
                 return <ListItemComponent
                           data={item}
                           itemMethods={methods}
                           key={index}
                         />
              })
              }
           </Row>
        </div>
    }

    render() {
        const {loading} = this.props

        return (
            <div className="list-wrapper">
                {
                    loading ? <Spinner visible={true}/>
                        :
                        this.getList()
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ListComponent.propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    methods: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default ListComponent
```

ListItemComponent:

```js
import React from 'react'
...

class ListItemComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
        }
    }

    toggleEditMode(){
        const editMode = this.state.editMode
        this.setState({editMode: !editMode})   
    }

    onEdit(id) {
        const itemMethods = this.props.itemMethods
        this.toggleEditMode()
        itemMethods.getItem({id: id})
    }

    onDelete(item) {
        //...
    }

    getFields(rowData, index) {
        return <div key={index}>
                {
                 rowData.map((itm, idx) => {
                   return <div key={idx}>{itm.label}: {itm.value}</div>
                 })
                }
            </div>
    }

    render() {
        const editMode = this.state.editMode
        const {data, itemMethods, strings} = this.props
        return (
            editMode ?
                <Form
                    id={data.id}
                    onSubmit={(data) => itemMethods.onEdit(data)}
                    validation={(data) => itemMethods.validation(data)}
                    onCloseForm={() => this.toggleEditMode()}
                />
                :
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <div>
                        <div
                            {this.getFields(data)}
                        </div>
                        <div className="controls">
                             <button
                                  className="btn btn-theme inverse danger"
                                  onClick={() => this.onDelete(data)}
                             >{strings.delete}</button>

                            <button
                                onClick={() => this.onEdit(data.id)}
                                className="btn btn-theme"               type="button"
                            >
                                {strings.edit}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Col>
        )
    }
}


ListItemComponent .propTypes = {
    strings: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    itemMethods: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        strings: state.strings.data || {}
    };
}


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null,
)(ListItemComponent )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

It was cause by ListComponent and the loading prop that was placed as condion in render function. When item was edited, prop loading was set to true, spinner became visible AND it was the only element in ListComponent and therefore the list items were unmounted

Answer (score 0):

Ensure each ItemComponent has a `key` prop set.  When React renders your list of items, it needs to know how to identify each element and React leaves it up to you to do this.  If you omit the `key` prop, React will destroy and re-create your list upon each re-render, which means calling the component constructor.

If you provide the exact code you're using, we can better point out where your issue is coming from.

You can read more about lists and keys [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Yes, each ItemComponent has a KEY prop. I updated my question by adding some code.